# Spring Boot Custom Authentication Provider redirect after login not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have implemented a Custom Authentication Provider into my Spring Boot app. This is to authenticate users against a 3rd party system and if successful I will redirect them to the /user page.

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
.
.
.
   private String privateResources[] = new String[]{"/user/**"};

   @Override
   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(publicResources).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(privateResources).hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(secureAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler());
   }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(this.customAuthenticationProvider);
    }
```

Below is part of my Custom Authentication Provider.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        ResponseEntity responseEntity = postAuthRequest(name, password);
        if (responseEntity != null && responseEntity.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuthorities);
        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException(responseEntity.getStatusCode().toString());
        }
    }
```

Then in my SecureAuthenticationSuccessHandler i have:

```
public class SecureAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException {

        handle(request, response, authentication);
        clearAuthenticationAttributes(request);
    }

    protected void handle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException {
        String targetUrl = "/user";
        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);
    }
```

The authentication works and I am receiving the OK status from CustomAuthenticationProvider.

But when the redirect to /user fires, spring returns:

User 'myuser' attempted to access the protected URL: /user

I have gone over and over this code and sure I am just missing something small, but just can not find the problem.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It depends on your database (table `USER_ROLE`, `APP_ROLE` , `APP_USER`)

Comment: `/user/**` doesn't match `/user` ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all...
What I have done is to change this:

```
.hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated()
```

to

```
.hasRole("USER").anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic()
```

That solved my problem. Not sure if it's the correct way of doing it, but it seems to work fine.